# Role add discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

```
require('discord-inline-reply');
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const { ownerID } = require("../../owner.json")
const db = require('quick.db')
module.exports = {
  config: {
      name: "roleadd",
          description: "Add a role to a member",
              usage: "m/roleadd <member mention/id> <role mention/role id>",
                  aliases: ['role add', 'radd', 'role']
                    },
                      run: async (client, message, args) => {

    let rMember = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
    if(!rMember) return message.channel.send("Please provide a user to add a role too.")
    let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name == args[1]) || message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id == args[1]) || message.mentions.roles.first()
    if(!role) return message.channel.send("Please provide a role to add to said user.") 


    if(rMember.roles.cache.has(role.id)) {
      return message.channel.send(`${rMember.displayName}, already has the role!`)
    } else {
      await rMember.roles.add(role.id).catch(e => console.log(e.message))
      message.channel.send(`${rMember.displayName} has been added to **${role.name}**`)
    }
  },
  };
```

The bot just gives role even if the user has a role lower than the user. I want to add a role position checking. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

To get member highest role you should use [`GuildMemberRoleManager.highest`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=highest), and use [`Role.rawPosition`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=rawPosition) to get its position in list!

So what you need is:

```js
if (rMember.roles.highest.rawPosition < role.rawPosition) return;
```

Comment: What's the difference between `Role.position` and `Role.rawPosition`?